# What are the input options for Matplotlib's colorbar "format" parameter?

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

Matplotlib's `colorbar` has `format` as one of it's parameters. According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colorbar_api.html), this parameters can be either a string or a [Formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.Formatter), but no further details are given. What are the standard options that can be passed as a string and will be understood by the colorbar or where are they listed?

Although I'm sure this information is somewhere in the documentation, I couldn't find it there or on another SO answer. I think this question can be useful to make it easier to find for other users in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format strings are addressed in the [matplotlib formatter documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.Formatter) in the  `matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)` section.
String formats are used the same way as in other languages like C, in which ".2f" will produce a number with two decimals showed as a string in your colormap.
E.g

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x,y)
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=-2, vmax=2)
fig.colorbar(mappable = colormap.ScalarMappable(norm, colormap.cool), format = '%.2f')
```

will show
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3q6H.png)
and

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x,y)
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=-2, vmax=2)
fig.colorbar(mappable = colormap.ScalarMappable(norm, colormap.cool), format = '%.4f m/s')
```

will show [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ8fR.png)